# What does "force oneself" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this in in the book, "Word Power Made Easy" which was:

> As in the case of the charitable-looking dowager who was approached by a seedy character seeking a handout.
>
> 'Madam' he whined, "I haven't eaten in 5 days." 'My good man,' the matron answered with great concern, 'you should force yourself!'

What does "force yourself" mean in this context? Does it mean to force yourself to eat (with pun intended) or force to do some work to be able to get money to buy food?

Comment: To me, it sounds like the matron did not understand that the man has nothing to eat but instead thought he has a difficulty with eating, so he suggested "force yourself." It's like an unintended joke.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's a cross post of the identical question at [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501879/what-does-force-oneself-mean-in-this-context) asked only a little over 2 hours ago.